# Define multiple variable in VUEX Mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import userStore from './user/userStore.js';
import VuexPersist  from "vuex-persistedstate";
Vue.use(Vuex)
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'


const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({
  key: 'vuex', // The key to store the state on in the storage provider.
  storage: window.localStorage, // or window.sessionStorage or localForage
})

export default new Vuex.Store({
modules:{
    userStore,
    plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin]
},

strict:debug
})
```

**userStore.js**

```
const state = {
    authUser:null,
    roles:null
}
const mutations  = {
    SET_AUTH_USER(state,userObj){
        state.authUser = userObj
    },
    SET_USER_ROLE(state,userRole){
        state.roles = userRole      
    }
}
const actions = {
    setUserObject :({commit},userObj) => {
        commit('SET_AUTH_USER',userObj)
    },
    setUserRoles :({commit},userRole) => {
        commit('SET_USER_ROLE',userRole)
    }
}
export default {
    state, mutations, actions
}
```

**Sidebar.vue**

```
created(){
    this.getRoles();
},
methods: {
    getRoles(){
        var _this = this
        _this.roles_data = response.data
        _this.$store.dispatch('setUserRoles',_this.roles_data)
        _this.fetch_roles()
    }
    fetch_roles(){
        console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
        // OUTPUT
        // (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]

        console.log(this.$store.state.userStore)
        // OUTPUT
        // {__ob__: Observer}
        // authUser: "NqStDm8ol3QGtoh0hzL7yhC3NP3HV0ktYKmYHI8TNiCjG4T4tLlv3pOEWFdA5CEh"
        // roles: Array(3)      
    }
}
```

**Dashboard.vue**

```
created(){
    console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
    // OUTPUT
    // null

    console.log(this.$store.state.userStore)
    // OUTPUT
    // {__ob__: Observer}
    // authUser: "NqStDm8ol3QGtoh0hzL7yhC3NP3HV0ktYKmYHI8TNiCjG4T4tLlv3pOEWFdA5CEh"
    // roles: Array(3)
}
```

hi
    I am working on vuex to store user roles access. I am storing two variable in store **1) authUser 2) roles**. **authUser** store user token and **roles** store user roles array. When i fetch role from api, i dispatch roles to **_this.$store.dispatch('setUserRoles',_this.roles_data)**. When i console in sidebar i get output like this

```
console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]

console.log(this.$store.state.userStore)
{__ob__: Observer}
authUser: "NqStDm8ol3QGtoh0hzL7yhC3NP3HV0ktYKmYHI8TNiCjG4T4tLlv3pOEWFdA5CEh"
roles: Array(3)
```

But when i console same thing in dashboard in created function it return **roles null**

```
console.log(this.$store.state.userStore.roles)
null

console.log(this.$store.state.userStore)
{__ob__: Observer}
authUser: "NqStDm8ol3QGtoh0hzL7yhC3NP3HV0ktYKmYHI8TNiCjG4T4tLlv3pOEWFdA5CEh"
roles: Array(3)
```

Am i missing something ?? or its a bug

Comment: could you provide the relevant parts of dashboard.vue?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim added dashboard.vue in my question. I just called roles from sidebar and dispatched it in vuex and then called in dashboard.vue. but it giving null in roles and value in authUser

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, you're putting the `plugin` declaration inside of `modules`, and it must be outside, at the same level.

You have:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({ modules:{
    userStore,
    plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin] },
```

And it should be:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
modules:{
    userStore
},
  plugins: [vuexLocalStorage.plugin]
}
```

Second, are you specifying the store module path to persist in the vuex-persistedstate plugin?

I don't see anywhere that declaration, and in that case, I think you should specify it as follows:

```
const vuexLocalStorage = new VuexPersist({ 
    paths: ['userStore'], //an array of the name of your store modules you want to persist
    key: 'vuex', 
    storage: window.localStorage 
})
```

And maybe would be necessary to set your module as namespaced, for example:

```
const namespaced = true 

const state = {
    authUser:null,
    roles:null 
} 
const mutations  = {
    SET_AUTH_USER(state,userObj){
        state.authUser = userObj
    },
    SET_USER_ROLE(state,userRole){
        state.roles = userRole      
    }
}
const actions = {
    setUserObject :({commit},userObj) => {
        commit('SET_AUTH_USER',userObj)
    },
    setUserRoles :({commit},userRole) => {
        commit('SET_USER_ROLE',userRole)
    }
}
export default {
    namespaced,
    state, 
    mutations, 
    actions
}
```

And also I recommend to use js-cookies instead of localStorage for security reasons, and your implementation would be as follows:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import userStore from '/path/to/userStore'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export default new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: [
        createPersistedState({
            paths:['userStore'], // YOU DON'T NEED TO SPECIFY KEY NAME, AS 'vuex' IS SET BY DEFAULT
            storage: {
                getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
                setItem: (key, value) => { 
                    Cookies.set(
                        key, 
                        value, 
                        { expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 20 * 60 * 1000) }) // Expiry time 60 minutes
                },
                removeItem: key => { 
                    Cookies.remove(key)
                    localStorage.removeItem('vuex')
                }
              }
            }
        )],
    modules:{
        userStore //REMEMBER TO NAMESPACE YOU MODULE!!
    }
})
```

And then, you could access to the persisted key from Cookies in the next way:

```
JSON.parse(Cookies.get("vuex")).userStore //JSON parsed to get the values
```